# WFS Authentification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, authentication

I have created and saved an authentication in QGIS for a password protected WFS service. In our company the login always consists of our username and the windows password.
Now a few days later I had to change my Windows password. As a result I can't use the service in QGIS anymore, neither with the old nor with the new password.  Even if I create a new service connection, so the same service address but a new name I can't log in anymore.

I have already deleted the qgis-auth.db under **C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default** and still I cannot use the service anymore.
Additionally, I also cleared the cache under **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\QGIS\QGIS3\cache** , also with the same result.
Are there any other folders where the configuration could be stored.